# Why can't I check if a specific index is a digit?

Tags: java

I have this program that requests input. At index values 0, 1, 3, and 4...the input is supposed to be a digit. However I'm having an error when compiling with that.

```
Time.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
        else if (militaryTime.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
                             ^
symbol:   method isDigit(char)
location: variable militaryTime of type String
Time.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
        else if (militaryTime.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(1)))
                             ^
symbol:   method isDigit(char)
location: variable militaryTime of type String
Time.java:49: error: cannot find symbol
        else if (militaryTime.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(3)))
                             ^
symbol:   method isDigit(char)
location: variable militaryTime of type String
Time.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
        else if (militaryTime.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(4)))
                             ^
symbol:   method isDigit(char)
location: variable militaryTime of type String
4 errors
```

Heres my code

```
//Check to make sure the colon is in
        //the correct spot
        if (militaryTime.charAt(2) != ':')
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        //Check to make sure all other characters are digits
        else if (militaryTime.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
        else if (militaryTime.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(1)))
        {
            System.out.println(militaryTime +
                " is not a valid miliary time." );
        }
```

militaryTime is a string that the user enters and these decision structures are setting up conditions to validate the data provided.

Answer (score 1):

`isDigit` is a *static* method in `Character`, not an instance method of `String`.  So instead of calling it with `s.isDigit` (for any `String` `s`), call it as `Character.isDigit`:

```
    else if (Character.isDigit(militaryTime.charAt(0)))
```

and so on.